# Conditional localField in mongoDB $lookup

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I would like to get a list of my `friends’ recent activities`.
`ReceiverId` and `RequesterId` vary depending on the `ActorId` sending the friend request.

As **I don't want to join my activities**, but **only those of my friends**, I tried to make a condition in a variable, and call the variable in `localField`.

The problem is that I get this error:

`MongoServerError: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'. Consider using $getField or $setField.`

Here is my request:

```
  const activities = await friendModel.aggregate([
    { $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          ReceiverId: ActorId,
          Status: 1
        },
        {
          RequesterId: ActorId,
          Status: 1
        }
      ]
    }},
    { $set: {
      fieldResult: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [ "$ReceiverId", ActorId ]
          },
          then: "RequesterId",
          else: "ReceiverId"
        }
      }
    }},
    { $lookup: {
      from: "activities",
      localField: "$fieldResult",
      foreignField: "ActorId",
      as: "activity"
    }},
    { $sort: { "activity._Date": -1 } },
    { $skip: request.pageindex * 3 },
    { $limit: 3 }
  ]);
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: You can specify only a field name in the `localField` of the `$lookup`. If you want to join conditionally, use the `let` and `pipeline` options.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @prasad_! Can you please make an example of what I should do? I've read the documentation on MongoDB, and I didn't understand anything.

Comment: I updated the request, I realized that it was not the right one...

Comment: What I don't understand is how I can modify `localField` via `pipeline`.

Comment: You can't modify `localField` directly. You can use a projection stage (e.g., `$addFields` or `$set` stage) to modify a field in a document.

Comment: Your code `localField: "$fieldResult",` - needs to be `localField: "fieldResult"`.

Comment: Thanks @prasad_, but it doesn't work.  `activity` is empty : `[{"_id":"627d77a9990fff996621d505","FriendId":4,"RequesterId":1,"ReceiverId":104,"Status":1,"__v":0,"fieldResult":"RequesterId","activity":[]},{"_id":"627d7828990fff996621d5ea","FriendId":5,"RequesterId":3,"ReceiverId":104,"Status":1,"__v":0,"fieldResult":"RequesterId","activity":[]},{"_id":"62a65626883ce6b43da9ec98","FriendId":16,"RequesterId":108,"ReceiverId":104,"Status":1,"__v":0,"fieldResult":"RequesterId","activity":[]}]`

Comment: In your `$cond` both the `then` and `else` need field's with `$` prefixed. For example, `"$RequesterId"`,

Comment: Thank you so much @prasad_, this is exactly what I needed! Now that I have this result, would you be how I could make all the `activity` results be in a separate object? I don't need `ReceiverId`, `RequesterId` and `Status` anymore.

The response would be:
`[{"_id":"62b1d1d5ce3a7f96e92aa6c9","ActivityId":4,"ActorId":108,"Type":3,"_Date":"2022-06-21T14:12:37.868Z","MovieId":0,"FriendId":0,"ContestId":0,"LookId":0,"__v":0},{"_id":"62af651cbc48f1e1b94c1935","ActivityId":1,"ActorId":3,"Type":3,"_Date":"2022-06-19T18:04:12.016Z","MovieId":0,"FriendId":0,"ContestId":0,"LookId":0,"__v":0}]`

Comment: You can use `$project` or `$unset` stages to control the fields you need in the final result.